# Read binary file and output base64: how to extract 6-bit groups?

Tags: assembly, base64, converters

I've started studying x64 assembly programming and my now exercise from school is to create a binary to base 64 converter.

I've already found the way to read a input file and but now i need to separate the binary number into groups of 6 number and then convert them.

I have now a file .asm that can read an input file and then show it in the command shell. But now I'm stuck on going through the data, read binary data and translate them into base 64.

Here's my file:

```
%define SYS_EXIT 60
%define SYS_READ 0
%define SYS_WRITE 1
%define SYS_OPEN 2
%define SYS_CLOSE 3
%define STDOUT 1

%define BUFFER_SIZE 2048

section .data
    fd dw 0
    
    Base64Table: db "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"
    Space: db " "
    Counter: dd 0
section .bss
    file_buffer resb BUFFER_SIZE
section .text
global  _start
_start:
    add rsp, byte 10h                       ;take the argument
    pop rdi                                         ;pop from the stack to put filename in rdi for sys_open command
    
    mov rax, SYS_OPEN                   ;system_call sys_open
    mov rsi, 0                                      ;flags 0, filename already gived before
    syscall                                         ;start call
    mov [fd], rax                               ;fd linked to rax value
    
    mov rcx, [Counter]

_read_write:
    mov rax, SYS_READ                       ;system_call sys_read
    mov rdi, [fd]                               ;file descriptor
    mov rsi, file_buffer                        ;char -> buffer
    mov rdx, BUFFER_SIZE                    ;buffer size 
    syscall
    

    cmp rax, 0                                  ;compare if end of string
    je _exit                                            ;jump equal to _exit
    inc rcx
    cmp rcx , 6
    je _addSpace

    mov rdx, rax                                ;length equal to system_call id 
    mov rax, SYS_WRITE                      ;system_call sys_write
    mov rdi, STDOUT                         ;id for STDOUT 1
    mov rsi, file_buffer                        ;size of output
    syscall

    jp _read_write                              ;jump to _read_write


_addSpace:
    mov rcx, 0
    mov [Counter], rcx
    mov rax, SYS_WRITE                      ;system_call sys_write
    mov rdi, STDOUT                         ;id for STDOUT 1
    mov rsi, Space                              ;size of output
    mov rdx, 1
    syscall
    
    jp _read_write

_exit:
    mov rax, SYS_CLOSE                      ;system_call sys_close
    mov rdi, fd                                 ;file descriptor
    syscall

    mov [file_buffer], dword 10         ;add file_buffer \n -> dword 10
    mov rax, SYS_WRITE                      ;system_call sys_write
    mov rdi, STDOUT                         ;sys_write call stdout
    mov rsi, file_buffer                        ;chars to write
    mov rdx, 1                                  ;length to write
    syscall

    mov rax, 60                                 ;system_call exit
    mov rdi, 0                                  ;int error code
    syscall
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think the point of the task is that **you** try to figure out how to do it. Try something and post your code and question here when you're really stuck. Simply asking for exmples, tutorials and other resources is off topic on Stackoverflow. And did you try searching for "assembly base64"?

Comment: It might help to look at the base64 algorithm and break it down into parts, then you can figure out how to code each part individually: http://fm4dd.com/programming/base64/base64_algorithm.shtm

Comment: I'm pretty sure there was a Q&A about exactly that problem on Stack Overflow within the last month.  Input as ASCII base 2 (`'0'` and `'1'` digits) so there was no need to "separate" them, just do the ascii->integer in groups of 6.

Comment: Thx for the answers.
Actually I've already begin the exercice and I have now file .asm that can read an input file and then show it in the command shell.
But now I'm stuck on going true the data, read binary data and translate them into base 64.
I'll put my file above.

Comment: I looked but didn't find the Q&A I was thinking of; maybe it didn't actually get answered and the poster deleted it.

Comment: `fd dw 0` reserves 2 bytes of space.  But you store/reload 8 bytes, overwriting the first 6 bytes of your base64 table.

Comment: @PeterCordes what do you suggest me to do because I'm totally lost and I can't find something obvious on the web